# Python SSH not giving full output

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to write a script that logs onto a remote machine, runs a command and returns the output. I'm doing this in python, using the paramiko library. However, for some reason the full output isn't being produced, only a single line of it.

In an attempt to isolate the problem, I created a local script, called simple, which runs the command and sends the output to a file, remote_test_output.txt. Then I simply sftp the file over instead. The file only contained the same one line. The only line of output is the same every time: the response code of the command.

When I do this all manually (ssh over, log in, and run ./simple), it all works as intended and the output file is correct. However, doing it through the script on my machine, it only returns the single line.

my code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(host, username, password)

ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/bin ./simple\n')

print "output:", ssh_stdout.read()+"end" #Reading output of the executed command
print "err:", ssh_stderr.read()#Reading the error stream of the executed command


sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.get('remote_test_output.txt', 'local_test_output.txt')
sftp.close()
```

What is returned:

```
response code: 128
```

What should be returned:

```
field1:value1
field2:value2
response code: 128
field3:value3
field4:value4
etc
```

Does anyone have any ideas why the command I'm trying to call isn't outputting normally?

I have to include the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable assignment or I get a library does not exist error.

Comment: Perhaps there's an incomplete redirection somewhere? Did you try 2>&1? What is ./simple doing, what is the basic command that ./simple runs?

Comment: @Dubslow it's a get status command. It gets the status of the other machine, temperature etc. I know its not a problem with the redirection because it works correctly if i ssh over and run it via the terminal

Answer (score 0):

According to paramiko's documentation, the "exec_command" method returns a Channel object. First question: did you try to set the bufsize parameter to one? The Channel object "behaves like a socket". So it is said in the documentation:

http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=149324975212197&set=a.128010850676943.34896.126277080850320&type=1&ref=nf

It means that recv() (and possibly read()) will only read the data that is in the read buffer. So whenever your read() call returns, it does not mean that the process was already executed on the remote side. You should use the exit_status_ready() method to check if your command was executed:

http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#exit_status_ready

And only after that can you read all the data. Well, this is what I guess. I may be wrong, but right now I cannot test my theory.